# Will cloning the whole state object in React lead to side-effects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm seeing code like this frequently in a React code base I'm working in and it feels like it will cause bugs, but I'm just speculating.

Code example:

```js
const newState = Object.assign({}, {}, this.state);
newState.x = '123';
newState.collection.push('abc');
this.setState(newState);
```

Does this code cause side-effects, perform worse, or is it just fine compared to the following?:

```js
this.setState(prevState => ({
  const collection = prevState.collection.slice();
  collection.push('abc');
  return {
    x: '123',
    collection: collection
  }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this will mutate the state if there are nested objects or arrays, since `Object.assign()` makes a shallow copy. so the line:

```
newState.collection.push('abc');
```

is actually mutating the collections array in state which can cause some nasty and unexpected bugs if your app grows

Comment: Oh boy. Just tested in the console and it's obvious that this is true. I'm still curious if there are other reasons not to set the properties you aren't changing since I can see the argument becoming "Oh thanks, we'll use this deep clone method"

Comment: It's not about cloning or copying, it's about being explicit about the changes we make to the data/state so React know what changes are made and what part of UI needs rerender. Being explicit really benefits us in terms of performance and optimizations.

Comment: with `state.collections.push()` the reference of the collections array is same as it was before the changes so React doesn't know now if there's any change to state and it won't reflect in our UI. So anytime anything changes in state we always return new state with changes applied, whether it be an object or an array. Always make a new one.

Comment: Found another reason in React's documentation. Updates are merged. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged. So if you copy the whole state and pass it back to setState, the merging can't work. It will replace the whole state

Comment: Yeah that's true, here's a good article talking about it: https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/